How to convert raw query to sqlalchemy, for an outer query
I am trying to convert this raw PostgreSQL query into SQLAlchemy:
SELECT a.main.id, a.main.name, a.access.user_id
(select count(*) from a.access where a.access.main_id = a.main.id and a.access.is_admin IS FALSE) as count
FROM a.main
INNER JOIN a.access ON a.access.main_id = a.main.id
where a.access.user_id = 'myusername' 
group by a.main.id, a.main.name, a.access.user_id


So for what I have done is this in SQLAlchemy
        subquery = session.query(
            func.count().label("count")
        ).filter(
            Access.main_id == Main.id,
            Access.is_admin.is_(False),
        ).subquery()

        stmt = session.query(
            Main.id,
            Main.name
            Access.user_id
            subquery.c.count
        ).join(
            Access,
            Access.main_id = Main.id
        ).filter(
            Access.user_id = 'myusername'
        ).group_by(
            Main.id,
            Main.name,
            Access.user_id,
            subquery.c.count
        ).all()


But when inspecting subquery it shows the query as:
SELECT count(*)
FROM a.access, a.main
WHERE a.access.main_id = a.main.id

This is where I am getting stuck. I tried to look at this question but that only handles the case for when the subquery is in the where clause.

Your question how to convert raw sql to sqlalchemy is obviously too broad, but I think this leads to a solution you could work with or try:
main_alias = aliased(Main)
access_alias = aliased(Access)
query = (
    session.query(
        Main.id,
        Main.name,
        Access.user_id,
        session.query(func.count())
        .filter(access_alias.main_id == main_alias.id, access_alias.is_admin.is_(False))
        .correlate(main_alias)
        .as_scalar()
        .label("count"),
    )
    .join(access_alias, access_alias.main_id == Main.id)
    .filter(Access.user_id == "myusername")
    .group_by(Main.id, Main.name, Access.user_id)
)

# Execute the query and retrieve the results
results = query.all()

the idea here is that it doesnt use an explicit subquery, but rather the same tables as aliases, to which it joins and correlates, and then selects the count with the appropriate filters (this puts the where-clause where it belongs)
I also think that grouping by subquery.c.count is a mistake in your original query?
There is also an example using SQLAlchemy Core which might be closer to your idea of explicitly using a subquery, but the syntax is obviously very different:
from sqlalchemy import select, func, and_

subquery = select([func.count()]).where(and_(a.access.c.main_id == a.main.c.id, a.access.c.is_admin == False)).label('count')
stmt = select([a.main.c.id, a.main.c.name, a.access.c.user_id, subquery]).select_from(a.main.join(a.access)).where(a.access.c.user_id == 'myusername').group_by(a.main.c.id, a.main.c.name, a.access.c.user_id)

Let me know if this helps
